# Get length of path of an arc in flutter

Tags: flutter, path, metrics

I am currently working on a `Flutter project` and I was trying to understand how `computeMetrics()` work.

**Android**

I previously implemented an `Android` solution to work with arcs, and it works. Part of the implementation is shown below:

```
   final RectF oval = new RectF(centerX - radiusArc, centerY - radiusArc, centerX + radiusArc, centerY + radiusArc);
    mPath.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle);

    PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(mPath, false);
    float[] xyCoordinate = {startPoint.x, startPoint.y};
    float pathLength = pm.getLength();
```

**Flutter**

and now I was trying to replicate the same in Flutter (`.dart`). For this reason, I am using the following implementation

```
  final Rect oval = Rect.fromLTRB(centerX - radiusArc, centerY - radiusArc, centerX + radiusArc, centerY + radiusArc);
  mPath.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle);

  List<num> xyCoordinate = new List<num>(2);
  xyCoordinate[0] = startPoint.x;
  xyCoordinate[1] = startPoint.y;

  List<PathMetric> pm = mPath.computeMetrics().toList();
  double pathLength = pm.iterator.current.length;
```

I have tried to follow a couple of examples to understand how could be possible to get the length of the path, but when using my implementation, `pm.iterator.current` is `null`
and therefore I am unable to get the `length`

I assume that I have understood wrongly how `computeMetrics()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to iterate over the List and add `length` of each `PathMetric` to get the path length.

```
double pathLength = 0;
pm.forEach((contour){
  pathLength += contour.length;
});
print(pathLength);
```

This is because, like the documentation of [`computeMetrics()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/computeMetrics.html) explains -

> A Path is made up of zero or more contours.

> A PathMetric object describes properties of an individual contour,
> such as its length etc.

Further, what `computeMetrics()` returns is an iterable collection of individual `PathMetric`s each corresponding to the individual contours that make up the Path. So in order to get the length of the Path, we need to add up the lengths of each `PathMetric` (contour) in the list, which is `List<PathMetric> pm = mPath.computeMetrics().toList();`

Comment: @bellotas, are you sure that `pm` is null? Or is it that `pm.iterator.current` is null?

Comment: Sorry, do not know what did I check yesterday. It is not null, and actually I got a result. Could you clarify in your answer what is the addition of all those item.length?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer to include further explanation.